# How can i free memory for left, right and temp without losing any data?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, b-tree

```
void split_into_children ( btnode& rootNode, btnode& root ) {
    long* key = & ( root->key[0] );
    int middle = root->capacity / 2;
    int i;
    btnode left = new node ( order );
    btnode right = new node ( order );
    btnode temp = new node ( order );
    for ( int i = 0; i < middle; i++ ) {
        left->key[i] = root->key[i];
        left->value[i] = root->value[i];
        left->capacity += 1;
        left->nodes[i] = root->nodes[i];
    }
    left->nodes[middle] = root->nodes[middle];
    for ( i = 0; i < root->capacity - middle; i++ ) {
        right->key[i] = root->key[middle + 1 + i];
        right->value[i] = root->value[middle + 1 + i];
        right->capacity += 1;
        right->nodes[i] = root->nodes[middle + 1 + i];
    }
    right->nodes[right->capacity] = root->nodes[root->capacity + 1];
    temp->key[0] = root->key[middle];
    temp->value[0] = root->value[middle];
    temp->nodes[0] = left;
    temp->nodes[1] = right;
    temp->capacity = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i <= left->capacity; i++ ) {
        if ( left->nodes[i] != NULL )
            left->nodes[i]->parent = left;
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i <= right->capacity; i++ ) {
        if ( right->nodes[i] != NULL )
            right->nodes[i]->parent = right;
    }
    if ( root->parent == root ) {
        right->parent = temp;
        left->parent = temp;
        temp->parent = temp;
        rootNode->parent = temp;
        rootNode = temp;
    } else {
        add_middle_to_parent ( rootNode, root->parent, left, right, root->key[middle], root->value[middle] );
    }
}
```

I have used left and right to split b+ tree node and temp to store the middle node which points to left and right. How can i deallocate memory o left, right and temp before returning from the function ?

Node class:

```
class node
{

public:

    long* key;
    int capacity;
    node** nodes;
    node* parent;
    long* value;

    node ( int order ) {
        key = new long[order + 1];
        value = new long[order + 1];
        nodes = new node *[order + 2];
        capacity = 0;
        parent = NULL;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= order + 1; i++ ) {
            this->nodes[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    ~node() {
        delete[] key;
        delete[] value;
        delete[] nodes;
    }

};
```

Comment: Uh... `delete left`, `delete right`, `delete temp`? That said, I'm terrible at C++, but wouldn't it be more idiomatic to allocate those three variables on the stack instead of as pointers? Also, seeing as you do `rootNode = temp` and similar assignments in your code, you might not want to deallocate the memory at all.

Comment: You can use smart pointers and watch them free their memory for you.

Comment: Why can't these objects just be on the stack?

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing or how your `node` class works.  I suspect it automatically deletes its subtree, and you want to stop it from doing that when you delete.  If that's the case, do exactly the same loop you did when you copied those pointers from the root, but NULL them out instead.

Comment: @millimoose i was not using delete left, delete right because the data will be lost. I can't store those three variables on the stack because left , right and temp are pointer to a B+ tree node which holds multiple pointer and values.

Comment: @Aesthete for the same reason stated in the above comment.

Comment: @paddy i have updated question with node structure.

Comment: So what data exactly would be deleted?  `node` doesn't even have a destructor.

Comment: @hellcoderz At the risk of overexposing myself on this: I was under the impression that it is highly preferrable in C++ to use stack-allocated objects to pointers, and to use copy constructors and overriding the assignment operator to make this work. (Obviously this isn't a hard-and-fast rule.) Also, if you don't want any of the data held by the nodes to be lost, *don't deallocate them* - you can't really free up the memory they hold but not lose the data (without copying). Or only deallocate the ones you know you don't need, but which ones those are is a detail of your btree algorithm.

Comment: @paddy i have added the destructor

Comment: @millimoose the problem is that if i don't deallocate anything then the memory used by the program is above 700MB for 1000000 nodes for 10 iterations. And the program gives memory overflow error if i use it with 5 more similar data structure together. All data structures have the same problem.

Comment: @hellcoderz And this is why people use garbage collectors. (Or refcounting smart pointers.) The real question you seem to be asking is "what memory can I deallocate given this btree implementation", and I'm not really sure if that's an appropriate one for SO.

Comment: @millimoose yup you are right. I will try to modify the code using smart pointers. Thanks